# web service giving error "Got Server returned HTTP response code: 504"

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl

I have a project in netbeans .Now i'm trying to add a login using a web service provided by my employer. What i've done so far is

1.Select 'add web service' by right clicking on the 'Web Services' in services panel in netbeans.

2. On the 'Add Web service' window opened ,i added the url of the web service provided as 'http://10.100.1.100/ADManager/ADlogin.asmx?wsdl' (the provided url is 'http://10.100.1.100/ADManager/ADlogin.asmx' and i added '?wsdl' at the end) and clicked Ok.
3. Dragged and dropped the added web service from the services panel to the code.

   Now the problem is ,when i debug my code the web service code i drage and dropped is showing exception shown below

"Failed to access the WSDL at: 10.100.1.100/ADManager/ADlogin.asmx?wsdl. It failed with:    Got Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: 10.100.1.100/ADManager/ADlogin.asmx?wsdl while opening stream from 10.100.1.100/ADManager/ADlogin.asmx?wsdl."

- Web service is running well because we have other applications in asp.net which utilise this web service for login.
- My netbeans IDE version is 7.1
- Tomcat version is 7.0.77

Comment: 504 is a Gateway timeout. Maybe an Proxy Problem?

Comment: to confirm that i used some services available online but most of them worked fine .